# IllegalStateException with naming parameters in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jenkins

I've been using tomcat and spring for a long time (more than a year). Everything worked out great.
Today, all of a sudden I get a weird error when starting tomcat:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List com.securegion.monitorcenter.dao.IncidentsViewRepository.getFixedIncidents(java.lang.String,java.util.List,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,int) but parameter 'text' not found in annotated query 'select * from siemincidents where fixed = 1 and descriptioninfo like %?1% and incidentseverity in ?2 and starttimestamp >= ?3 and endtimestamp <= ?4 order by starttimestamp desc limit ?5, ?6'!`

I didn't knew what to do, but no one used the method so I deleted it. Then I restarted tomcat, and got

`Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List com.securegion.monitorce
    nter.dao.IncidentsViewRepository.getFixedIncidents(int,int) but parameter 'start' not found in annotated query 'select * from siemincidents where fixed = 1 order by starttimestamp desc limit ?1, ?2'!`

Again I didn't know what is this, so I deleted the tomcat server entirely from eclipse and created it again. This worked for half an hour, and then I got the same problem! Than, deleting tomcat doesn't help. 
What is weird is the the service in the DAO starts with "get" and not "find". I thought that maybe tomcat is confused, so I changed "get" to "fetch". Didn't help. I read here that instead of writing "?1" I should write ":text". But understand that writing with "?" worked for over a year, so I have MANY parameters with "?" - too much work for an annoying bug (it worked for over a year). I've checked all my files, and nothing important is changed today, so I don't know what file caused it.

At the begging it only happened to me, but now it happens to a colleague. We use JENKINS to deploy our server, and JENKINS crashes in

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [/etc/jenkins/jobs/mcg_DeployToDev/workspace/mcg/target/mcg.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:185)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:989)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:967)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:721)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:670)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Deployed application at context path /mcg but context failed to start

    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:611)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:291)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:102)
    ... 17 more
org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Deployed application at context path /mcg but context failed to start

    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:611)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:291)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:185)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:989)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:967)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:721)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:670)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

If it matters, I'm using tomcat 8.

What can I do? It is such a huge problem that perhaps I'm just missing a minor glitch... What is it?

Comment: Did you check the database you are reading from?

Comment: What should I check? I can select from it, what else do I need?

Comment: I don't know... did anything change in the database? Are you reading from a view?

Comment: I was reading from a view, but if I commented the code it told me that another code that is reading from a table is wrong when I restated tomcat. And I am not aware of a change in the DB.

Comment: Most likely the view has become corrupted. Try rebuilding it.

Comment: I got problems on tables also after I commented out the view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What fixed it is changing the '?' to :param and adding @Param("param") before the parameter in the method.

Meaning that the select method:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM agents limit ?1, ?2", nativeQuery = true)
public List<AgentEntity> getAll(int start, int length);
```

has changed to

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM agents limit :start, :length", nativeQuery = true)
public List<AgentEntity> getAll(@Param("start") int start, @Param("length") int length);
```

That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can works in the following ways

1. With param
   @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM agents limit :start, :length", nativeQuery = true)
   public List getAll(@Param("start") int start, @Param("length") int length);
2. Without param
   @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM agents limit :start, :length", nativeQuery = true)
   public List getAll(int start,int length);

Answer (score 0):

The question is too old but I faced the same issue. My issue was due to the `tomcat` version. I switched back to `tomcat 7` from `tomcat 8` and code starts working as expected.
Seems like `Tomcat 8` is not supporting `?` in `Native Query`.