# Exception using 'in' and not '=' in Where on a Spring selection

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am using Spring to select a value. This is the query in the repository:

```
@Query(value = "select * from incidents where descriptioninfo like %:descriptioninfo% and fixed = :fixed and starttimestamp > :startTime and deviceid in (select id from devices) and deviceid in (select deviceid from devicesmaps) and (incidentseverityid in (:incidentseverityid))  order by starttimestamp desc limit :start, :length", nativeQuery = true)
public List<IncidentEntity> getByStarttimestampAndDescriptioninfoAndSeverityAndFixed(@Param("startTime") String startTime, @Param("descriptioninfo") String descriptioninfo, @Param("incidentseverityid") List<Integer> incidentseverityid, @Param("start") int start, @Param("length") int length, @Param("fixed") int fixed);
```

If I run it I get the exception:

> Parameter with that name [descriptioninfo] did not exist

Weirdly, changing the selection to:

```
@Query(value = "select * from incidents where descriptioninfo like %:descriptioninfo% and fixed = :fixed and starttimestamp > :startTime and deviceid in (select id from devices) and deviceid in (select deviceid from devicesmaps) and (incidentseverityid = (:incidentseverityid))   order by starttimestamp desc limit :start, :length", nativeQuery = true)
public List<IncidentEntity> getByStarttimestampAndDescriptioninfoAndSeverityAndFixed(@Param("startTime") String startTime, @Param("descriptioninfo") String descriptioninfo, @Param("incidentseverityid") List<Integer> incidentseverityid, @Param("start") int start, @Param("length") int length, @Param("fixed") int fixed);
```

(only changing from

```
(incidentseverityid in (:incidentseverityid))
```

to

```
(incidentseverityid = (:incidentseverityid))
```

fixes the exception and retrieves the required values!

The smallest change possible, from 'in' to '=' on a different parameter ('incidentseverityid' and not the parameter in the exception 'descriptioninfo') fixes the problem!

Why?

- The select with either 'in' or with '=' works in MySQL Workbench with the same parameters.
- Please don't tell me to change :param to ?1 [because I had a problem with ? in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508278/illegalstateexception-with-naming-parameters-in-tomcat).
- Note that the table is dumped and restored and even repaired in MySQL, and its engine is changed between InnoDB and MyISAM.
- Also note - even creating a class named 'IncidentsServeritiesEntity' as a son and using it with a proper int ID instead doesn't help - only switchig from 'in' to '='.

  ```
  @Param("incidentseverityid") List<IncidentsServeritiesEntity> incidentseverityid
  ```
- The selection doesn't work if I use either:

  ```
  identseverityid in :incidentseverityid
  ```

or:

```
    (identseverityid in (:incidentseverityid))
```

(with brackets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a bit ugly but works: define what is missing with `=` instead of `in`, create a long `or` command and pass it.

```
String allParams = "";

for (String currParam : param)
{
    allParams += ("param = " + currParam + " or "); 
}

allParams = allParams .substring(5, allParams .length() - 3);
```