# Using named parameters for method when I use @Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-data-jpa, I want update something, I have annotated my method in PaySupplierSettleBillRepository as

```
public interface PaySupplierSettleBillRepository extends JpaRepository<PaySupplierSettleBillEntity, Long>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<PaySupplierSettleBillEntity> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("update PaySupplierSettleBillEntity p set p.payTime=:payTime,p.paymentOrder=:paymentOrder, p.transferTime=:transferTime, p.transferBank=:transferBank, p.transferOrder=:transferOrder, p.operatorName=:operatorName, p.remark=:remark where p.orderNumber=:orderNumber")
    int updatePayInfo(PaySupplierSettleBillEntity entity);
}
```

I am getting following exception while starting

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract xxxxxx
```

how I fix it ? thinks.

Comment: I don't want use ` Custom Implementations for Spring Data Repositories` way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not how you write a `@Query` with named parameters. Take a look at the example from Spring documentation here (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters).

If you want to provide an object as param, you can do something like this.

```
@Query("UPDATE Entity E SET E.name = :#{#entity.name}")
public void updateEntity(@Param("entity") Entity entity);
```

Comment: This is awesome

Answer (score 2):

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method` can be thrown when a method has redundant parameter which is not used in the `@Query`.

In your case, `entity` should be used in the SQL query like it's mentioned in the previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56053250/5962766 or you should replace it with specifying necessary parameters one by one in the method signature.

Related: [IllegalStateException with naming parameters in tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508278/illegalstateexception-with-naming-parameters-in-tomcat)