# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters

Tags: java, spring, hql

when i use this query then always show error why? am using MappedSuperclass in audit class.

```
@Query("select new  com.brite.domain.CurrencyConversion(ins.id,ins.contractType,ins.symbol,ins.exchange,ins.currency,ap.allocationQty,ap.createdDate,ca.baseCurrency,hd.close) from ActualPortfolio as ap JOIN  Instrument as ins on ins.id=ap.instrument.id JOIN  HistoricalData as hd on hd.instrumentId = ins.id   Join ClientAccount as ca on ca.accountId = ap.clientAccount.accountId  where ap.clientAccount.accountId =:accountId and ap.createdDate = (select MAX(pf.createdDate) as date from ActualPortfolio pf where  ap.clientAccount.accountId =:accountId and pf.createdDate =: createdDate) and hd.dateTime = (select to_char(MAX(pf.createdDate), 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00') as date from ActualPortfolio pf where  ap.clientAccount.accountId =:accountId and pf.createdDate =: createdDate)")
```

Pojo class looks

```
        @Entity
        @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
        public class Transaction extends Audit {    
            private Long Id;     

        }
```

and audit class is

```
        @MappedSuperclass
        public class Audit {

            @Column(name = "createdDate", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
            @CreatedDate
            @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
            private LocalDateTime createdDate;

        }
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for
>   method public abstract java.util.List
>   com.brite.repository.InstrumentRepository.getInstrumentForCurrencyConverstion(java.lang.String,java.time.LocalDateTime)
>   but parameter 'Optional[createdDate]' not found in annotated query
>   'select new 
>   com.brite.domain.CurrencyConversion(ins.id,ins.contractType,ins.symbol,ins.exchange,ins.currency,ap.allocationQty,ap.createdDate,ca.baseCurrency,hd.close)
>   from ActualPortfolio as ap JOIN  Instrument as ins on
>   ins.id=ap.instrument.id JOIN  HistoricalData as hd on hd.instrumentId
>   = ins.id   Join ClientAccount as ca on ca.accountId = ap.clientAccount.accountId  where ap.clientAccount.accountId
>   =:accountId and ap.createdDate = (select MAX(pf.createdDate) as date from ActualPortfolio pf where  ap.clientAccount.accountId =:accountId
>   and`enter code here` pf.createdDate =: createdD`enter code here`ate)
>   and hd.dateTime =`enter code here` (select
>   to_char(MAX(pf.createdDate), 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00') as date from
>   ActualPortfolio pf where  ap.clientAccount.accountId =:accountId and
>   pf.createdDate =: createdDate)'!

Comment: Please post the annotated method signature.

Comment: Maybe your repository parameter createdDate does not have annotation @Param("createdDate") or parameter name differ from name in hql

Comment: As mentioned in below answer, you are using optional created date as parameter. Change it to allow the unwrapped date object. But yiu haven't posted your java part of code. So please correct your question for people to help you.

Comment: You should add repository method signature after @Query

Comment: You 'd better remove constructions like "from ActualPortfolio as ap JOIN  Instrument as ins on ins.id=ap.instrument.id". You can use "from ActualPortfolio ap JOIN ap.instrument ins" or "from ActualPortfolio ap, Instrument ins where ins.id=ap.instrument.id" instead

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70962589/5962766

Answer (score 3):

thanx, something was wrong with my query. we don't need to put space after colon ':' in query

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you are passing Optional Argument to method. That might be causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

verify Method parameter names with Query dynamic parameter names. if both are same  it will  work.

EX:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur when the parameter name has a mismatch with the variable name.